# Alternatives to the word "credential"

Tags: copywriting

I am currently working on an account management page, where the user can edit their sign in credentials.  I'm looking for a strong CTA term that is not "Manage your credentials". There is secondary text that helps the user understand what they can manage, but I would rather have a strong primary term as well.

Comment: most people would understand "login details"

Comment: What is wrong with "Account Management" if that is the page it goes to?

Comment: It's a sub page within account management.

Answer (score 1):

How about these:

- "Edit account info"
- "Edit login info"

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the application one of these may work in place of **User Credentials**...

**User Qualifications**

**User Authority**

If you are just looking for a way to let the user know there is a way to change their login information then Google currently uses **Signing in**...

[image: google signing in]